# How to query sum and distinct in one sqlite query?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with the following data:

```
Class Student Score Date
  A     Tom    10   Aug 1
  B     Dave    9   Aug 1
  A     Jan     7   Aug 2
  B     Jack    8   Aug 2
  A     Matt    5   Aug 3
  B     Dave    8   Aug 4
  A     Matt    8   Aug 4
```

Each student can only have one score in each day but can have multiple scores for multiple days.

I want to do a query to list total score of each class and number of student in each class. How can I do that with one query?

The expected result:

```
Class Student_Count Total_Score 
  A        3            30
  B        2            25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by class, count the distinct number of students and sum the scores of all the students:

```
SELECT Class,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Student) Student_Count,
       SUM(Score) Total_Score
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Class;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=df37147d9fe7758adb6ab3873cce03da).

Answer (score 1):

Use a distinct student count:

```
SELECT Class,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Student) AS Student_Count,
       SUM(Score) AS Total_Score
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Class;
```